# How can i share a partition (without win locking it on hibernite)

Tags: dual-boot, mount, windows, ntfs, hibernate

I know ubuntu can mount my win(ntfs) drives. My problem is that i always Hibernate my win (& linux), and windows locks all NTFS drives when i hibernate it. And I know i can mount locked win drives as read-only ,but thats read-only!

So, basically, I need a drive to share my files between win & ubuntu.

Alos, I have tried to mount linux drives in win ( failed, files in mounted drive in windows wasnt updating! maybe it was becuse i hibernite both OS's?), and ext readers (well u cant say its sharing that way!).
And NO, I don't want to remove hibernate to mount the win drive. And No, I dont want to shutdown my windows.

So ... Any suggestion? would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For sharing partition in dual boot You should create and NTFS partition and set up it to mount automatically on Ubuntu start. You can edit the file /etc/fstab and include a line like this:

/dev/sda10 /media/Winbugs7/ ntfs-3g defaults,user,rw    0   0

Where /dev/sda10 is the partition and /media/Winbugs7 is the (existing!) directory where the partition will be mounted.

for more details refer this link
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions

Comment: windows locks NTFS partitions on Hibernate, so i cant mount them with 'rw'. I can mount them in RW mode if i remove hibernate or mount them in read-only mode. neither an acceptable option for me.